# Angular Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myTableController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular.
I am getting the error " [ng:areq] Argument 'myTableController' is not a function, got undefined"

I tried to debug it with alerts and I am not hitting Test4 at all

Why is that?

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
    alert("Test1");
var app1 = angular.module("myTableModule", []);
    alert("Test2");
app1.controller("myTableController", function($scope) {
    alert("Test4");
});
    alert("Test3");
```

The following is my html source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/currentSettings.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
        </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container body-content">
     <div ng-app="myTableModule" ng-controller="myTableController">
        <table>
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th>Company Name</th>
                 <th>Customer Name</th>
                 <th>Document Name</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="currentSetting in currentSettings">
                 <td>{{currentSetting.companyName}}</td>
                 <td>{{currentSetting.customerName}}</td>
                 <td>{{currentSetting.docType}}</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
     <hr />
     <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2016 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
     </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
  <!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
  <script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
     {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"4373e3d6a6314b6bb4066b12f1b12d1f"}
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:55964/60de32f396fe4106a9655183ab19f24b/browserLink" async="async"></script>
  <!-- End Browser Link -->
```

Comment: How are you trying to consume your controller?  You are most likely referencing it before the above code is parsed and rendered.

Comment: try  placing ng-controller in a separate div inside ng-app `<div ng-app><div ng-controller><div><div>`

Comment: I did that originally but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer the .js file of your controller in the html file.

Let say if your controller is in a file called controller.js

then in your html you have to write like below

```
<script src="controller.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Comment: I am referring it  in  Shared    _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Please check the path of the js file is correct or not,see whether it giving you 200 or 404.Also what is the js file name in which you your angular module and controllers.

Comment: I am getting the following error:                                           angular.js:13642 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myTableController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/ng/areq?p0=myTableController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:68
    at assertArg (angular.js:1911)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1921)
  ....

Comment: Try removing all other js files, keep only angular.js and your controller's file

Comment: Your code is working on my system by just adding the angular.js

Comment: Thank you, I did that. The same issue.

Comment: Which version of angular you are using

Comment: In you HTML I cannot see where you are referencing your controller js

Comment: This line:  <script src="/Scripts/currentSettings.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I had to recreate the project. Also my path to the web service was not correct.
Thank you for all the help and support